# React Native - Conditional rendering doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I have a timer and I want to use the activity indicator before it starts.

I prepare a state

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

after a promise it changes state

```
setIsLoading(false);
```

the console reports `false`
this is the rendering

```
  {isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
  ) : (
     <Text style={styles.text}>{`${time.hours ? time.hours : ''} ${
    time.hours ? ':' : ''
  }  ${time.mins} : ${time.secs}`}</Text>
  )}
```

the console reports `true`

That's it. But it doesn't work. The indicator stays there and the content doesn't show up. Where is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: "It stays there and doesn't show up" – *what* stays there and *what* doesn't show up?

Comment: I guess he means the activity indicator

Comment: How can it stay there and not show up at the same time?

Comment: true I messed it up sorry. The indicator stays there and the content doesn't show up